# Slack View_submission not posting to Current Window

Tags: python, flask, slack, slack-api

I am using the below code, to define Modal `blocks` and then submit the Modal via flask to slack. The slack command works fine and brings up the Modal UI. When I submit the Modal, it takes me to `view_submission()` method. In this method, I am calling `client.chat_postMessage()` to post a response to the current window, but this does not happen. If I pass in a Slack `ChannelID`, it posts the message to the channel, but when I pass in a Slack `User_Id` of the User I am interacting with via a DM, the message gets posted to the bots home screen. How do I post a response to the same window that the slash command was executed/requested from? I am looking for functionality similar to the `/remind` app in slack.

[Response from /reminder command within same window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FkYE.png)

```
import os, logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

from slack_bolt import App

app = App(
    token="",
    signing_secret="",
)


@app.middleware  # or app.use(log_request)
def log_request(logger, body, next):
    logger.debug(body)
    next()


# Step 5: Payload is sent to this endpoint, we extract the `trigger_id` and call views.open
@app.command("/jarvis")
def handle_command(body, ack, client, logger):
    logger.info(body)
    ack(text="Accepted!",
        blocks=[
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "b",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": ":white_check_mark: Accepting New Request!",
                },
            }
        ],
    )

    modal_block = open("modal.json", "r").read()

    res = client.views_open(
        trigger_id=body["trigger_id"],
        view={
            "type": "modal",
            "callback_id": "settings-modal",
            "title": {"type": "plain_text", "text": "Settings Form"},
            "submit": {"type": "plain_text", "text": "Submit"},
            "close": {"type": "plain_text", "text": "Cancel"},
            "blocks": modal_block,
            "private_metadata": "what is gona come here?"
        },
    )
    logger.info(res)


# Step 4: The path that allows for your server to receive information from the modal sent in Slack
@app.view("settings-modal")
def view_submission(ack, body, client, logger):
    ack()
    logger.info(body["view"]["state"]["values"])
    user_Id = body["user"]["id"]
    client.chat_postMessage(channel=user_Id, text="submitted, wait please!!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.start(5000)
```

`modal.json`

```
[
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": ":wave: Hello!\n\nUse this tool wisely!!!"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "input",
            "block_id": "source_block",
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Source Tenant Name",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "element": {
                "type": "plain_text_input"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "input",
            "block_id": "dest_block",
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Destination Tenant Name",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "element": {
                "type": "plain_text_input"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "input",
            "block_id": "settings_block",
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Choose Settings"
            },
            "element": {
                "type": "multi_static_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select 1 or more Settings from the list below"
                },
                "initial_options": [
                    {
                        "value": "value-0",
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "BU"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "value-1",
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "JT"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "BU",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-0"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "JT",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": ":desert_island: Hawaiian",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Camp",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "TenMgmt",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-4"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": ":taco: Tacos",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-5"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": ":green_salad: Salad",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-6"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": ":stew: Indian",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-7"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use `response_url` to post response to the same window .

**Details:**

> Depending on the source, the interaction payload your app receives may
> contain a response_url. This response_url is unique to each payload,
> and can be used to publish messages back to the place where the
> interaction happened.

https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#message_responses

Also, **about using `chat.postMessage` for DM**

 You need to use `conversations.open` to get the DMId which will be passed as channel in `chhat.PostMessage`.

https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open

Comment: Adding a `response_url` forces me to change the modal, to include a `channel_select` or `conversations_select` block, but I do not want users to select where to post the message. If we check `/remind` app's modal block, it also does not include a `response_url`, so how is it posting the follow up message? I believe its via `trigger_id`, but not sure which method or how to use it

Comment: Meaning to say that a response is sent in the same channel window by `client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel_id, text="submitted, wait please!!!")` if this request is triggered from any channel, but the same response does not appear in a DM/IM. How do I make it so it gets posted in a DM/IM?

Comment: I had tried this too. I can get the DM Id from the URL, if i use that Id and pass it directly to `client.chat_postMessage(channel=DM_ID)`, it says channel not found

Comment: The `conversations_open()` always returns me the Bot's Id as DM ID, i think its because the token is the bots token. I believe this is the same reason as to why response gets posted to bot's window. How do I make it so it gets posted to IM/DM window?

Comment: You need to identify slackId of the user who have initiated the command and then work with that. I am not aware about the complete workflow so can't help much

Comment: Thank you Suyash, I tried this too, but it either says 'Channel Not found' or doesn't post to user's page.